# Updating your frame widgets in tkinter

Tags: tkinter, widget, frame

So I'm having this little problem with my program, that is as follows:
I have a frame in which I have several widgets and a button.
I wish the function bound to that button to update the frame so that
it adds a widget to the end of the column (I'm using grid manager).
So the function takes an input from an entry field and adds it under
all the other stuff in the frame as a label for example.
Now I'm just struggling with how to code it to work. I'm quite new to
Tkinter and don't know how to proceed. I know how to get the info out of
the entry field, but I don't know how to make an algorithm that updates
the UI as intended.

EDIT:
I have a function that adds stuff from the entry field as a label to the grid. The problem I'm having is that when the button is pressed, the input should be put in the end of the column. If I hard code the function to add the label to a certain block in the grid like:

```
something.grid(column=0, row=3)
```

it will put all the labels after the first on top of each other, when I want them to be added in the next row of the last one added.
I tried something like this:

```
for i in range(len(list_of_labels):
  something = label(self.__window, text="list_of_labels[i]")
  something.grid(column=0, row=i+2)
```

but it didn't work too well. I hope this is clearer..

Comment: (First Question Review): you might show some code to illustrate your problem.

Comment: There's nothing special about this problem, just do whatever you do to put the first items in the grid: create the widget then call the `grid` method. What part of that are you struggling with?

Comment: Use some variable to keep how may rows you have. And increase it after every `grid()`